# Terminar un ciclo while

Tags: python

Necesito saber como hago para terminar este ciclo `while`.

```py
registro = "Digite su codigo CDIA: \n\n" 

while registro:  
  
    datos_digitados = input(registro)
    
    datos = datos_digitados.upper()

    validar_inscripcion(datos)
```

Se esta llamando  una función que solicita unos datos y cuando se cumplen, vuelve y pide que se digite el codigo y la idea es que no los siga pidiendo. Gracias.

Comment: que tratabas de hacer con while registros, cuando while es un iterador que va a iterar mientras la condicion (una cadena?) sea siempre verdadera....

Answer (score -2):

Hice esto, reemplazando tu funcion por una nueva variable, e imprimiendolo al terminar la iteracion, desconozco si tu input debe ocurrir "n" cantidad de veces.

```
registro = "Digite su codigo CDIA: \n\n" 

x=0

while registro:  
  datos_digitados = input(registro)
  datos = datos_digitados.upper()
  x=x+2
  break

print(str(x))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que hacer un bucle while si el código dentro solo se ejecuta una vez?

Comment: Este codigo no tiene sentido.. la pregunta ya no tenia sentido si OP no explicaba porque hacia algo asi...

Comment: Y a mi que me dicen? Yo no publique la pregunta